# Find the optimum number of non uniform bins

Tags: algorithm, r, size, bin

R - Problem: to find the optimum number of non-uniform bins to show a range of data points.

I have a bunch of data points (let us assume different prices of different mobiles). I need to categorize these mobile phones into some categories (based on the price). The bin size (in this example refers to the price range) need not be uniform (there might be lots of mobiles in the low price category and few in the long tail category).

Is there any efficient algorithm to find the optimum number of bins required and the number of data points (in this case mobile phones) which shall go into each category.

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/histogram-with-uniform-vs-non-uniform-bins, and this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram-for-n-where-n-ranges-from-30

Comment: Depends a lot on what you want to do with the data.  Just plot a histogram?  Generate a purchasing algorithm to maximize sales profit?  and so on.

Comment: The optimum number is seven.

Comment: @Dwin you forgot to show your sigfigs. :-)

Comment: If anybody knows any data set for which my algorithm won't produce efficient solution, please let me know.

Comment: I am a big fan of using normal quantile plots or cdf plot so that I don't really need bins to see the distribution.  If I am trying to cluster the data then there are established and effective methods (GMM, etc) to determine the actual clustering.  I would use that to determine cluster membership.  The constraint here is that you might have small sample size data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard formula, but wanted to post as it seem to work well with data set i tested.

1. Find the average price of all the mobiles.

   Ex: 5 mobiles with prices 10, 20, 40, 80, 200

   Avg is 350/5 = 70
2. Subtract minimum price from average price: 70 - 10 = 60 -> name it N1
3. Subtract avg price from Max price: 200 - 70 = 130 -> name it N2
4. Find the ratio N2/N1 : 130/60: Roughly 2

   This indicates that it is better to have 2 bins at the lower price range for every 1   bin at higher range.
5. So, for example take 2 bins below 70. Range 0 - 35(2 mobiles), 36 - 70(1 mobile)

   1 bin above 70: Range 71 - 200(2 mobiles)

As you can see, number of bins and bin sizes are reasonably optimal.